# photoproduction process (vector mesons)

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I am reading a paper on photoproduction.  I have a question about the following statement:  We propose "Z(4430)$^{\pm}$ can be produced by the meson photoproduction process $\gamma$p$\rightarrow$Z(4430)$^{+}$n$\rightarrow$$\psi^{\prime}$$\pi^{+}$n.''

My question is if the process:

$\gamma\bar{p}\rightarrow$Z(4430)$^{-}$n$\rightarrow$$\psi^{\prime}$$\pi^{-}$n

is implied and not explicitly written?

Comment: Have you checked baryon number in your second, conjectural,process?

Comment: @CosmasZachos:  Thank you for your comment...  I see, $\bar{p}$ has a baryon number of -1 in the second conjectural process, so this would not conserve baryon number.  Then would the process instead be $\gamma$$\bar{p}$$\rightarrow$ Z(4430)$^{-}$$\bar{n}$$\rightarrow$$\psi^{\prime}$$\pi^{-}$ $\bar{n}$ ?

Comment: I don't see why not, if there is a $Z^-$....

Comment: @CosmasZachos:  Yes, indeed!  Thank you for your help!